# Crash when trying to iterate threw map

Tags: c++11

OK I am having a crash when I try to use my getGrades method. Here is the main parts that I am having issues with.

```
class Student {
public:
    void setId(string);
    void setName(string, string);
    void setGrades(string, int);
    string getId();
    string getName();
    void getGrades();


private:
    string id_; 
    Name name_; 
    Grades grades_;
};

void Student::setGrades(string course, int score) {
    grades_.insert(make_pair(course, score));
}

void Student::getGrades() {

    for(auto it = grades_.begin(); it != grades_.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it -> first << ' ' <<  it -> second << endl;
    }
}
```

if I put the code from getGrades into the setGrades method it works fine, but in it's own method it crashes with:

```
0 [main] a 5144 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace
to a.exe.stackdump
```

Even though I took out the other methods that are working fine and just left (what I think) the key elements are, I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Edit: I forgot to add..

```
typedef pair<std::string, string> Name; // first name, last name
typedef map<std::string, int> Grades; // map courses to scores
```

Edit 2: As requested..

```
vector<Student> addStudent(int count, int x, vector<Student>& vStu, string file) {
string line, first, last;

ifstream infile(file);

while (getline(infile, line)) {

    vStu.push_back(Student());
    vStu[count].setId(line);
    getline(infile, line);
    istringstream iss(line);

    if (!(iss >> first >> last)) {
        cout << "failed to get name" << endl;
        break;
    }
    vStu[count].setName(first, last);

    getline(infile, line);
    istringstream iss2(line);
    if (!(iss2 >> x)) {
        cout << "failed to get class number" << endl;
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        string sClass;
        int grade;

        getline(infile, line);
        istringstream iss3(line);

        if (!(iss3 >> sClass >> grade)) {
            cout << "failed to get class and grade" << endl;
            break;
        }

        vStu[count].setGrades(sClass, grade);
    }
    count++;
}
return vStu;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
vector<Student> vStu;
int count = 0, x = 0;


if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "Incorrectly called" << endl;
    cout << "    "  << argv[0] << ' ' << "<filename>" << endl; 
    return 1;
}

addStudent(count, x, vStu, argv[1]);
count = vStu.size();
for (int i = 0; i<count;i++) {
    cout << vStu[i].getId() << endl;
    cout << vStu[i].getName() << endl;
    vStu[count].getGrades();
    cout << endl;
}   


}
```

Comment: What is `Grades` an alias for?

Comment: Not sure I but I think I saw what you asking and added it on, let me know if that edited didn't cover what your asking for.

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes those functions

Comment: added in both the adding a student and the main method.

Comment: `vStu[count].getGrades();` You mean `vStu[i].getGrades();`? VTC as typo.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!!!!!!! well I am totally embarrassed now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> vStu[count].getGrades(); You mean vStu[i].getGrades();? VTC as typo. –  T.C.

Typos... let that be a lesson for everyone, no matter how many times you have checked your code it is the simplest things your are going to miss.